# dot is not working in htaccess as defined in htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't have much knowledge in .htaccess and I am struggling with regex concept in .htaccess.

I want same url concept as on facebook for user profile but dash(-), underscore(_), dot(.) this I want in url also currently my url rule is as follow:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,\_,A-Z,\_,\-,0-9.][!pagenotfound|home|abuse/*|user/*|start/*|login/*|account/*|message/*|find/*|cms/*|accountactivation/*|register/*]*)/?$  memberspersonalinfo.php?members=$1 [QSA]
```

This pattern have some error

but when in my browser domain.com/username is comming it's working fine but when url will be `domain.com/test-test` or `test_test` or `test.test` it redirects to `PAGE NOT FOUND PAGE

and in my .htaccess rule defined to follow that rule like abuse/* have dynamic id wherever I have used star `(*)` they are referencing dynamic value. When I will do rule like

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z,\_,A-Z,\_,\-,0-9.]*)/?$  memberspersonalinfo.php?members=$1 [QSA]
```

It's working fine but when I moveto home page then it calls `memberspersonalinfo.php` page it self.

I am trying to explain my Question again with htaccess script

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex  index.html index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound
ErrorDocument 403 /pagenotfound
ErrorDocument 401 /slapme/pagenotfound
ErrorDocument 500 /pagenotfound

#index
RewriteRule ^index.html$  index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index$  index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home$  index.php [L]

#nopage
RewriteRule ^pagenotfound$  nopage.php [L]

#Regitration
RewriteRule ^register/createaccount$  userregistration.php [L]

#Regitration Confirmation
RewriteRule ^register/accountconfirmation$  registrationconfirm.php [L]

#Activation Regitration
RewriteRule ^accountactivation/([a-z,\_,A-Z,\_,\-,0-9]*)/([a-z,\_,A-Z,=,\_,\-,0-9]*)$ registrationactivation.php?UsercontactID=$1&AccountId=$2 [L]

#after login
RewriteRule ^user/main$  after_login.php [L]

#Payment Detail
RewriteRule ^user/myaccount$  useraccount.php [L]

#Logout
RewriteRule ^user/logout$  logoutuser.php [L]

#creategroup
RewriteRule ^start/creategroup$  http://domain.com/start/creategroup [L,R=301]

#Forgot Password
RewriteRule ^user/forgotpassword$  http://domain.com/user/forgotpassword [L,R=301]

#Login
RewriteRule ^login/userlogin$  http://domain.com/login/userlogin [L,R=301]

#Remove account
RewriteRule ^account/remove$  removeuseraccount.php [L]

#Send an email page
RewriteRule ^message/?$  contacttouser.php [L,QSA]

#Report any site user page
RewriteRule ^abuse/([0-9]*)/$  reportsiteuser.php?reportUserID=$1 [L,QSA]

#CMS FIND FRIENDS PAGE
RewriteRule ^find/friend$  http://domain.com/find/friend [L,R=301]

#CMS TERMS OF USE PAGE
RewriteRule ^cms/howitworks$  howitworks.php [L]

#CMS CREATE OWN SLAP PAGE
RewriteRule ^cms/createownslap$  createownslap.php [L]

#CMS BRAND OR PRODUCT PAGE
RewriteRule ^cms/brandorproduct$  brandorproduct.php [L]

#CMS APPS AND FEATURES PAGE
RewriteRule ^cms/appsandfeatures$  appsandfeatures.php [L]
```

this my full htaccess code everthing is working fine all rules are working but when i add

```
#group personal profile page page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/abuse(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/user(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/start(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/login(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/account(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/message(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/find(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cms(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/accountactivation(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/register(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/social(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/css(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/js(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/userimages(.*)
RewriteRule ^([a-z,\_,A-Z,\_,\-,0-9.]+)/?$  memberspersonalinfo.php?members=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it always loads memberspersonalinfo.php

Comment: The last rule always redirects to the script, even when the URL contains only the domain. ¿What is the purpose of the first rule? I suggest you add some URL examples, explaining when the incoming URL should be redirected. It's hard to guess from the rules what you want.

Comment: i just simply want that after domain name any alphanumeric character will come that redirect to memberspersonalinfo.php but url should not contain all url's in second rule.